# Из JSON в ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, kotlin

Не могу разобраться и вывести все объекты в ListView.
Входные данные:

```
{
 "elements":[
  {
   "firstname":"Uri"
  },
  {
   "firstname":"Maria"
  }]
}
```

Выходные данные или что должно получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если так, то добираюсь только до одного элемента.

```
val deSerial = gson.fromJson(result.value, Data::class.java)
val item = deSerial.elements[0].firstname
Log.d(">>>>>","$item")
```

**Data**

```
data class Data(val elements:ArrayList<Elements>)
data class Elements(val firstname:String)
```

Так намерен выводить значения:

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr)  
listView.adapter = adapter
```

**Main activity**

```
btn.setOnClickListener({getData()})
        val arr = arrayListOf<String>("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4")
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr)
        listView.adapter = adapter
    }
    
    private fun getData(){
        val url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/17xutb"
        url.httpGet().responseString { _, _, result ->
            when (result) {
                is Result.Failure -> {}
                is Result.Success -> {
                    val builder = GsonBuilder()
                    val gson: Gson = builder.create()
                    val deSerial = gson.fromJson(result.value, Data::class.java)
                    var item = deSerial.elements
                    Log.d(">>>>>","$item")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Log**
D/>>>>>: [Elements(firstname=Uri), Elements(firstname=Maria)]

Comment: Ну вот в `Data` у вас массив всех элементов и есть. По индексу можете получить любой. Не понятно в чём именно проблема.

Comment: @eugeneek, это вывод поэлементно. Мне нужно вывести сразу все элементы. Т.е. если их будет 50, то 50, а не вручную.

Comment: `val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deSerial.elements)` разве так не работает?

Comment: @eugeneek, дополнил вопрос листингом. Сейчас выводит так. Мне нужно эти два элемента из лога вывести в лист. То, что сейчас находится в листе - это в качестве примера висит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` в качестве последнего параметра может принимать лист `String`. То есть вам нужно создать `List<String>` из вашего `ArrayList<Elements>`, вытащив из каждого элемента `firstname`. В Kotlin можно сделать с помощью `map`:

```
val deSerial = gson.fromJson(result.value, Data::class.java)
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
        deSerial.elements.map { it.firstname })
listView.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: Проверю - отпишу.

Answer (score 0):

> Если так, то добираюсь только до одного элемента.
>
> ```
> val item = deSerial.elements[0].firstname
> ```

Ну раз взял нулевой элемент через `[0]`, то только его и получил. Надо для всех элементов.

Comment: Я обращаюсь к определённому индексу массива.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/207546)

Comment: @eri, почему не является?

Comment: @Qwertiy, похоже на то, что просто повторил часть вопроса. Если добавить сюда "Для этого используйте map или forEach" будет похоже на ответ...